# Deluxe Gift Voucher in opencart does not show images in frontend

Tags: php, html, opencart

I am working on a site http://www.lemongrasshouse.com.au/ But certainly the http://www.lemongrasshouse.com.au/index.php?route=account/voucher thumb images after gift voucher name is not showing. I am using the plugin http://tlecode.com/deluxe_voucher
Can anyone help me please to solve the problem
Thanks
Somdeb

Comment: Which OpenCart version?

Comment: Opencart version 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit these two files, Open controller file:

```
catalog\controller\account\voucher.php
```

**Find:**

```
$data['voucher_themes'] = $this->model_extension_total_voucher_theme->getVoucherThemes();
```

**Replace with:**

```
    $data['voucher_themes'] = array();
    $results = $this->model_extension_total_voucher_theme->getVoucherThemes();

    $this->load->model('tool/image');
    foreach($results as $result){
        if($result['image']){
            $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], 50, 50);
            // Or use your custom size instead of 50
        } else {
            $image = false;
        }
        $data['voucher_themes'][] = array(
            'voucher_theme_id' => $result['voucher_theme_id'],
            'name' => $result['name'],
            'image' => $image
        );
    }
```

Then open view file:

```
catalog\view\theme\{YOUR_THEME}\template\account\voucher.twig
```

**Find:**

```
<input type="radio" name="voucher_theme_id" value="{{ voucher_theme.voucher_theme_id }}" checked="checked" />
```

and

```
<input type="radio" name="voucher_theme_id" value="{{ voucher_theme.voucher_theme_id }}" />
```

**Add after them:**

```
{% if voucher_theme.image %}
    <img src="{{ voucher_theme.image }}" alt="{{ voucher_theme.name }}" class="img-thumbnail" />
{% endif %}
```

Save files and clear your caches (ocmod, vqmod, twig caches).

Comment: recheck your edits and make sure caches are cleared. it works on my side.